# ahk assistance with set timer

Tags: autohotkey

hello guys so I'm kind of a noob when it comes to ahk and I would require your help in order to add a delay in this small script

```
$F3:: ; 
{
Send % step ? "{²}{y}**ADD 50 MS DELAY THERE**{s}{a}" : "{²}{s}{a}"
SetTimer, timeout, -10500, step := 1
}
return

timeout:
   step := ""
return
```

thanks in advanace for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Sleep function](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm):

```
Sleep,50
```

Comment: You need to convert that ternary operator to a multiline `if…then…else`. You then need to `Send…` `Sleep…` `Send…` on separate lines.